# Make my LAN independent for local routing (DHCP + static routing) while connected to a cable modem with DHCP which cannot be disabled (ISP)

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp, isp, static-ip

First of all, I want to say that my knowledge about networking is basic (I'm a web developer, not a net admin :D)

I have a local network composed by:

- A **cable modem with routing capabilities** (Let's call it **A**) which is **MANAGED ALMOST COMPLETELY BY THE ISP**, so I can barely rename Wi-Fi SSID, encryption and password, NAT and not much more, all of that through their own admin page in an external webpage, not in a local admin panel as most of routers do.
- **Another router** (Let's call it **B**) with 4 eth ports configured to receive WAN through the 4th eth.
- **2 PCs** that I am willing to assign **IPs dynamically** through Router **B**'s DHCP server
- **2 PCs** that I need to assign **static IPs** through the MAC/IPs static routing table under DHCP configurations in Router **B** (Need static IP to be able to reference them through hosts file in the LAN)

**WHAT DO I NEED?**

I need to connect all devices through Wi-Fi to the network and I need them to be ruled by my router **B**, which is the one I can manage. I would like the Router **A** to only serve as a default gateway (but I cannot change any configuration on it other than the ones I mention in the beginning, since ISP is blocking the admin panel) and let the rest of the local dynamic and static routing (DHCP on router **B**) be done by the router **B**.
Currently, router **A** has its DHCP enabled, and I can't change that.

**EXTRA DETAILS**

Since the ISP installed this router **A** (New ISP), I started experiencing slowness in resolving local routing, that's why I'd prefer everything to be routing  under my router **B**, and then default to router **A** only for internet concerns.

**FINAL NOTES**

Would a subnet help to fix these issues? If so, how should I proceed to configure a subnet? I've never done so. And I assume this is a special case for that since I can only edit my router **B**'s configuration.

Hope I'm clear enough and that someone could help me configure my LAN to work as I require under these conditions, otherwise let me know what's unclear or what possible options are if my idea is not feasible.

Any help would be ***SO MUCH*** appreciated!

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this post and sorry if I made it too long but wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything!

Comment: If you are really connecting router B to router A with the former's WAN port to a latter's LAN port, all you need to do is make router B use a different subnet for its LAN from router A's. You won't be using router A as the "default gateway" of the "real LAN". Neither would you want to if you think "routing with router A makes the LAN slow", I suppose?

Comment: It's recommended to almost always, if not always, run a personal router downstream from an ISP's due to data security and privacy for downstream devices.  While you could set up Router B with a WAN firewall, you'd be double NAT'ing all WAN traffic and it's more of a headache than it's worth.  As @TomYan mentioned, simply setup Router B with a separate subnet (192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.3.0/26, etc.) and have it serve as the master DHCP server for all downstream devices.

Comment: I am not sure if he can avoid double NAT though. First of all you will need to be able to disable it on router B, then you'll need to be able to add static routes for the new subnet to router A, no?

Comment: If he instead join the two routers by connecting with router B's LAN port, things would probably go insane if he can't disable the DHCP server on router A, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks @TomYan and @JW0914! If I turn DHCP on in my router B and still have router A do what it wants (hold DHCP enabled, etc), then I connect all devices through wifi to the router B and set a subnet on it, should the DHCP server in router B take precedence over DHCP in router A when the different devices ask for IP?

Comment: If you are connecting to router B's WAN port to a router A's LAN port, the DHCP server on router A would only be relevant to router B itself (more precisely its WAN interface).

Comment: Gotcha @TomYan! I'll try to do that and let you know guys how it went. Thank you very much to both of you!